# Number of positive integers with distinct digits which are less than $10^n$, where $n$ is an integer.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I need to select numbers with unique digits which are less than $10^n$ where $n$ is an integer. Suppose $n=2$, then I've to select all numbers less than $100$ which have unique digits.

$0-9$ all digits are unique there are $10$ ways.

For two digit numbers:

_ _ We can fill the unit's place in $10$ ways. Ten's place gets filled in $8$ ways so total it'll be $80$ numbers.

So in all it should $10+80 =90$ but the actual answer is $91$. What's wrong with the above approach?

Answer (score 2):

When you put a $0$ in the units place it does not prohibit any value for the tens place, so there are $9$ choices instead of $8$.  That is the extra possibility.  It is often easier to fill the restricted places first.  Here the tens place cannot accept a $0$, so there are $9$ choices for the tens place.  For each of them there are $9$ choices for the units place, giving $81$ possible two digit numbers.

Answer (score 0):

We can define a function $f(n, k)$ that computes how many numbers, written in base $k$, have unique digits and are less than $k^n$. Clearly, $f(0, k) = 1$ because there is only one number less than $k^0 = 1$, namely $0$. Going forward, we can also reformulate our problem as follows: find how many numbers, written in base $k$, have unique digits and contain at most $n$ digits. First we can compute the number of $n$-digit numbers that can be formed in base $k$. There are $k \choose n$ ways to choose $n$ digits from the available digits in base $k$ and $n!$ ways to permute those digits (each permutation gives us a number with unique digits). Thus, there are $n! \cdot {k \choose n}$ ways to form $n$-digit 'numbers' with unique digits in base $k$. However, we want to remove or subtract out the numbers that begin with $0$ (e.g. we would not consider something like $01234 = 1234$ as a $5$-digit number in base $10$ but rather a $4$-digit number). To account for this, suppose we fix $0$ as the leftmost digit of a number. There are $k - 1$ digits in base $k$ left to use in the number (as all digits must be unique and we have used $0$), and we need to choose $n - 1$ more digits to complete the $n$-digit number. This means there are ${k - 1 \choose n - 1}$ ways to choose the remaining digits for our $n$-digit number in base $k$ and $(n - 1)!$ ways to permute those digits (as $0$ is fixed in the leftmost digit slot). Thus, there are $(n - 1)! \cdot {k - 1 \choose n - 1}$ ways to construct $n$-digit numbers with unique digits that have $0$ as the leftmost digit. Putting this altogether, we have that there are
$$n! \cdot {k \choose n} - (n - 1)! \cdot {k - 1 \choose n - 1} = (k - 1) \cdot \displaystyle\prod_{i = k - n + 1}^{k - 1} i$$
$n$-digit numbers in base $k$ less than $k^n$ (excluding those that don't begin with $0$), which means
$$f(n, k) = \begin{cases}
            1 & n = 0\\
            ((k - 1) \cdot \displaystyle\prod_{i = k - n + 1}^{k - 1} i) + f(n - 1, k) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
If you prefer a non-recursive definition, then you may rewrite this as
$$f(n, k) = 1 + \displaystyle\sum_{j = 1}^{\min \{n, k\}} ((k - 1) \cdot \displaystyle\prod_{i = k - j + 1}^{k - 1} i) $$
Note that I've added $\min \{n, k\}$ because if we ever have $n > k$, then it's clear by the pigeonhole principle that we cannot form an $n$-digit number with unique digits in base $k$ such that $n > k$.
In your example, $k = 10$ and $n = 2$, and we have
$$1 + \sum_{j = 1}^2 (9 \cdot \prod_{i = 10 - j + 1}^{9} i) = 1 + 9 + 81 = 91$$